# Creating File Download Links MVC3 Razor View with Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am attempting to create links in my view so the end user can download the files in my model. In internet explorer I can right click and download from the link but I cannot left click (it does not open the file). Firefox gives me a message when I click the file that it does'nt know how to open this address, because the protocol (d) isn't associated with any program.

Here is how I am creating the link.

```
    @{
            foreach (var EpubFile in item.files)
            {
                if(File.Exists(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadFileDirectory"] + EpubFile.FileReference))
                {
                    string link = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadFileDirectory"] + EpubFile.FileReference;
                    <a href="@link">@EpubFile.OriginalFileName</a>                              
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the link is prefixed with `http://` and is a full or partial path in URL form, not in filename form. E.g., `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\foo\files\myfile.txt` should be `/files/myfile.txt`. You can use `Server.MapPath` to obtain the relative path of a file under your web application root.

Comment: so I need to convert my physical path to a virtual path for this to work