# links to physical files in mvc

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to read the files from a physical directory and display as links on the view.
I am getting the links to the file, but the files are not being downloaded on click of the link.
Below is the code. Please help. When i hover over the link i can see the file as file:///c:/Test/Test.doc But on click of the link the file is not downloaded.

```
  public class Documents: Controller
  {

    public ActionResult Documents()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //Read the files from directory and display
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetDocumentlinks()
    {
        string data = "";
            foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:/Test"))
                {

                    var uri = new Uri(s);
                    var converted = uri.AbsoluteUri;
                    data = "</br>" + data + "<a href='" + converted + "'>" + Path.GetFileName(s)      + " </a> </br></br>";

                }

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

   }




   <div id="links"></div>
   $(document).ready(function () {

   LoadTrainingDocsGrid();
   });

   function LoadTrainingDocsGrid()
   {
   $.ajax({
     cache: false,
     url: '../Document/GetDocumentlinks/',
     dataType: 'json',
     type: 'GET',
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     success: function (data) {
         debugger;
         $('#links').html(data);
     }
     });
      }
```

Comment: if they are not mapped in virtual directory it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600897/creating-file-download-links-mvc3-razor-view-with-model) provides details about the difficulty you are having.

It describes the relationship between physical and virtual folders and how to change the links you are currently rendering (physical file links) into the proper links (http:// urls referring to the files in your **virtual** folders) to get the behavior you are looking for.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need to read the files from a shared Path which I can't move under a web folder. The files under the same shared location needs to be read from the website that will be hosted on different servers.

Comment: You should not need to 'move' anything.  Can you address the shared path manually via a UNC?  That should be good enough to map (not move) a virtual folder underneath your site that points at the other server.